# How do you SUM values based on a MIN date?

Tags: mysql, sql

Working on an exercise for school trying to calculate the number of points scored by a basketball player ONLY during their first game.

So if I have a table that reports lots of games (Separate rows for 1st and 2nd half) that looks like this:

```
Game Date   Player  Half    Points
1990-01-01  Mike    1        10
1990-01-01  Mike    2        10
1990-01-03  Mike    1        5
1990-01-03  Ben     2        8
1990-01-05  Kelly   1        4
1990-01-05  Kelly   2        4
1990-01-07  Kelly   1        10
```

And I want it to end up like this:

```
Game Date   Player  Points
1990-01-01  Mike    20
1990-01-03  Ben     8
1990-01-05  Kelly   8
```

How would I do this?

I have been trying to use the code:

```
SELECT min(game_Date), player, sum(points);
```

But it keeps counting points for ALL games, not just points scored during the 1st game, of which there can be one record for the first half and one record for the second.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Of course this query will count all games.  All you did was getting the min_date and sum of points for all players.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find the players' first games, like this

```
 select player, min(game_date) as firstGameDate
 from yourtable
 group by player
```

and then get the points in that game by joining to the table again

```
 select yourtable.player, firstgame.firstGameDate, sum(points) as firstGamePoints
 from yourtable
      inner join 
 (
 select player, min(game_date) as firstGameDate
 from yourtable
 group by player
 ) firstgame
      on yourtable.player = firstgame.player
      and yourtable.game_date = firstgame.firstgameDate
 group by yourtable.player, firstgame.firstgameDate
```

Some varieties of SQL allow you to use ranking functions which could eliminate the need to join to the table itself, but this will work in all varieties.

Comment: Thanks. One question - where does "firstgame" as in "first game.firstgamedate" come from?

Comment: FirstGame is the name I gave to the subquery that gets the first game date for each player just before the `on` clause

Answer (score 1):

You have to use your logic.  First you have to only grab the first game for each player (inner query).  Then from there, you count the points

```
SELECT t.game_date, t.player, SUM(t.points)
FROM some_table t
JOIN (
    SELECT player, MIN(game_date) AS min_date
    FROM some_table
    GROUP BY player
) a ON a.plyer = t.player AND a.min_date = t.game_date
GROUP BY t.player, t.game_date
```

Comment: You have a typo in the `JOIN` `ON` clause - _plyer_ -> _player_.

Answer (score 0):

Sub query approach of getting the result is given below

1. Filter the results only getting Player's first games.

> Select min(Game_Date),Player from 
>        basketball group by Player;

2. Use the results from first query to find each player's sum of scores in first game.

> Select Game_Date, Player,sum(points) as first_play_points from 
>   basketball where (Game_date,Player) in   (Select min(Game_Date),Player
>   from  basketball group by Player)  group by Game_Date, Player;

Working fiddle can be found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ehGySNoPUNThZU7Rn8CA5e/1)

Comment: I may be mistaken, but my recollection is that this approach can struggle to use an index

Comment: @Strawberry I am not sure how much performance gap is there between the two approaches in modern optimizers. People normally use subquery because it has more readability. Some DB treats subquery and joins equally internally (I am not sure about MySQL). I just presented an alternate approach. The OP can further research on that. I beleive whole purpose of SO is not only providing right answer but also alternate approaches.